# INavigation not working with Prism in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, dependency-injection, xamarin.forms, prism-6

I am new to prism with xamarin form. To implement prism with xamarin I have installed three packages:

1. Prism.Core
2. Prism.Forms
3. Prism.Unity.Forms

and inherits App from PrismApplication like this:

```
  public partial class App : PrismApplication { }
```

I want to bind View with ViewModel from code behind file like this:

```
    this.BindingContext=ViewModelLocator.ViewModelName
```

For this, I've found this code. This code is in App.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();
    BindViewModelToView<LoginRegisterViewModel, MainPage>();
}
public void BindViewModelToView<TViewModel, TView>()
{
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(typeof(TView).ToString(), () => Container.Resolve<TViewModel>());
}
```

Here is my ViewModel Code:

```
public class LoginRegisterViewModel : BindableBase
{
    #region Private variables
    private readonly IPageDialogService _diglogService;
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    public  Action Test { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public LoginRegisterViewModel(IPageDialogService diglogService, INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _diglogService = diglogService;
         _navigationService = navigationService;

    }
    #endregion
}
```

It's working fine when I remove `INavigationService`.

But it's showing error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> ```
> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "DSMobile.ViewModels.LoginRegisterViewModel", name = "(none)".
>
> Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>
> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Prism.Navigation.INavigationService, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?
> ```

---

At the time of the exception, the container was:

```
Resolving DSMobile.ViewModels.LoginRegisterViewModel,(none)    

Resolving parameter "navigationService" of constructor DSMobile.ViewModels.LoginRegisterViewModel(Prism.Services.IPageDialogService diglogService, Prism.Navigation.INavigationService navigationService)

Resolving Prism.Navigation.INavigationService,(none)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long after the question was asked but I resolved this issue by manually mapping INavigationService to PageNavigatonService like this

```
container.Register<INavigationService, PageNavigationService>();
```

I hope this helps anyone else that comes across this issue.